# Small System of First Order Coupled PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have reduced my problem to the following:

I have a function, $b(\theta,\phi)$, which is defined implicitly (up to integration constants) by the differential equations:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial b}{\partial\phi} &= -\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\tan{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\frac{\partial b}{\partial\theta} \tag 1 \\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial\theta} &= -\cos{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\sin{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\tan{\theta} \tag 2
\end{align}

Combining, I deduce that:

$$\quad \frac{\partial b}{\partial\phi}=\sin^2{\theta}\sin^2{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]} \tag 3$$

My problem is to find an explicit, or implicit expression for $b(\theta,\phi)$, without derivatives. All my variables are real.

I am not sure if it is helpful, but I worked out that $(2)$ is compatible with the following

$$\cos{\theta}\tan{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}=f(\phi)+\text{const} \tag 4$$

which yields $(2)$ on differentiation with respect to theta. Finally, we can add also any constant times $\sec{\theta}\cot{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}$ to the LHS of $(4)$, and it is still compatible with $(2)$. But I can't find a way to develop it to make it consistent also with $(3)$. So, I am now stuck. I am not sure whether

1. There is no solution - the differential equations are incompatible (the worst outcome), or
2. There is no analytic solution, but the equations could be solved numerically in a computer (I could live with that), or
3. There is an analytic solution (which would be best, of course).

I would very much appreciate any advice on how to proceed.

Thanks.
$$
\newcommand{\del}{\delta(\theta,\phi)}
\newcommand{\xx}{x(\theta,\phi)}
$$
**Continuation**

Following the suggestion of @JJacquelin continue by substituting their solution, function $b(\theta,\phi)$, into Eq. (2). First define, for brevity, two new variables:

$$\del=\phi-b(\theta,\phi)$$
$$\xx=\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)$$

Substituting into the solution of (3) given by @JJaquelin, allows it to be re-written

$$\tan{\del}=\frac{\tan{\xx}}{\cos{\theta}} \tag 5$$

which we use below.

In order to substitute into (2), differentiate the solution of (3) w.r.t. $\theta$ and use the new variables
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial b}{\partial\theta}&=&-\frac{1}{1+\tan^2{\del}}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\frac{\tan \xx}{\cos{\theta}}\right)\\
&=&-\cos^2{\del}\frac{\cos{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\tan{\xx})+\sin{\theta}\tan{\xx}}{\cos^2{\theta}}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, we have from (5) that $\tan{\xx}=\cos{\theta}\tan{\del}$ but this is a function $f(\phi)$ only, from (4) (which solves(2)), and thus $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(\tan{\xx})=0$ and therefore

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial\theta}=-\cos{\del}\sin{\del}\tan{\theta}$$

which is (2). Thus all is consistent as long as

$$\cos{\theta}\tan{(\phi-b(\theta,\phi))}=f(\phi)=\tan{(\phi\cos(\theta)+g(\theta))}$$

$f(\phi)$ and $g(\theta)$ can be *any* functions and need to be determined from boundary conditions (which were not specified in the OP).

Comment: Hi Paul ! You wrote : All is consistent as long as

$f(\phi)=\tan{(\phi\cos(\theta)+g(\theta))}\quad$ . 

$f(\phi)$ and $g(\theta)$ can be *any* functions. I cannot understand how a function  of only one variable $f(\phi)$  can be equal to a function which  includes a second  variable $\theta$ not constant.

Comment: @JJaquelin As answer, I see it like a constraint. To take a more familiar analogy, if we have some function, f(x), then we can set f(x)=7, and this fixes x to a point. Similarly, if we have some other function g(x,y) and we set g(x,y)=h(x), then this defines some locus within the x-y plane (which otherwise was unconstrained). Thus, setting, e.g. $\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)=f(\phi)$ defines a locus in the $\theta-\phi$ plane. Is that reasonable in your view? Perhaps it is then a mistake to say (as I did) that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta))=0$ in that case?

Comment: Well I understand that. This means that the variables $\phi$ and $\theta$ are not independant but are related defining a curve on the $\phi,\theta$ plane. Then the solution we are looking for is not a general solution but a particular solution valid only on this curve. Do you agree with this wording of the problem ?

Comment: I noticed that I made some typos in my original question (for which, my apologies that I only noticed them just now). All the derivatives in my question are supposed to be partial, although I see that I did not include the correct "$\partial$" in my denominators. I will correct that now. But perhaps it was implicit anyway that all should be partial, since $b(\theta,\phi)$ is a function of two variables.

Comment: I have fixed the partial derivative typos. I wonder if this changes the discussion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question but a compendium of my results.

FIRST CASE : Considering equation $(1)$ ALONE :
$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial\phi} +\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}\tan{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\frac{\partial b}{\partial\theta}=0 \tag 1 $$
This is a first order quasilinear PDE. Thanks to the Charpit-Lagrange method or of the method of characteristics, the general solution expressed on the form of implicit equation is :
$$b(\theta,\phi)=F\Big(\cos\big(\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\big)\tan(\theta)\Big)\tag{S1}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$ $$

SECOND CASE : Considering equation $(2)$ ALONE :
$$\frac{d b}{d\theta} +\cos{\left[\phi-b\right]}\sin{\left[\phi-b\right]}\tan{\theta}=0 \tag 2$$
This is a first order non-linear ODE. Solving it leads to :
$$b(\theta,\phi)=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{h(\phi)}{\cos(\theta)}\right) \tag{S2}$$
$h(\phi)$ is an arbitrary function.
$$ $$

THIRD CASE : Considering equation $(3)$ ALONE :
$$\frac{d b}{d\phi}-\sin^2{\theta}\sin^2{\left[\phi-b\right]}=0 \tag 3$$
This is a first order non-linear ODE. Solving it leads to :
$$b(\theta,\phi)=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)  \tag{S3}$$
$g(\theta)$ is an arbitrary function.
$$ $$

CASES OF SYSTEM OF EQUATIONS :

If the equations (1),(2),(3) are not considered independently but as a system of equations, the solutions (S1) , (S2) , (S3) are equivalemt, but with not independant functions $F,h,g$, insofar they exist and can be found.

For example the system of equations (2) , (3), has a solution insofar (S2)=(S3) which obviously supposes $$h(\phi)=\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)$$ 
$h(\phi)$ is no longer a function of $\phi$ alone but is a function of $\phi$ and $\theta$. So one cannot put it into (S2) in order to find the general solution of the system of equations.

Reciprocally  $g(\theta)$ is no longer a function of $\theta$ alone but is a function of $\phi$ and $\theta$. So one cannot put it into (S3) in order to find the general solution of the system of equations.

This tends to show that the system of equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ has no solution in general. One can expect a particular solution not valid for any couple $(\phi,\theta)$ but valid only on a curve which equation satisfy $h(\phi)=\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)$ .

Comment: Thank-you for this latest compendium. There are quite a lot of details there for me to assimilate. But first, a question: I noticed in your Case 2 and 3, you notated full derivatives, not partial. Is the difference significant? For my original question, they should all be partial (though I notice, with apologies, that as typed, they are ambiguous - which I will fix now).

Comment: That is only a matter of habit of notations. This changes nothing in my answer;

Comment: I confirm by direct differentiation the quoted solutions for the three cases considering the equations as independent.

Comment: I will go back to my original problem (which is a practical physics problem) to check the correspondence between the variables there with those of the derived mathematical question asked here, in order to see if there are any inconsistencies in interpretation etc. This is likely to take me some time, since I will do a "deep" check.

Comment: I have discovered issues with the physical "set-up" of this problem, and I cannot now be confident that the equations, as stated, are really valid for my problem. The discussion here was very helpful in getting me to this "conclusion", and I thank you for your help. I will uptick the compendium as the best answer to the mathematical problem I posted, and I consider this post as answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d b}{d\phi}=\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(b-\phi) \tag 3$$
$b(\phi)=\psi(\phi)+\phi$
$$\quad \frac{d \psi}{d\phi}+1=\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\psi)$$
$y(\phi)=\tan\left(\psi(\phi) \right)$

$\sin^2(\psi)=\frac{\tan^2(\psi)}{1+\tan^2(\psi)}=\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}$

$\frac{dy}{d\phi}=(1+y^2)\frac{d\psi}{d\phi}\quad\implies\quad \frac{d\psi}{d\phi}=\frac{1}{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{d\phi}=\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\psi)-1=\sin^2(\theta)\frac{y^2}{1+y^2}-1$

$$\frac{dy}{d\phi}=\sin^2(\theta)\:y^2-(1+y^2)=-\cos^2(\theta)\:y^2-1$$

$$\int d\phi=-\int\frac{dy}{\cos^2(\theta)\:y^2+1}$$

$$y=-\frac{\tan\left(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+c\right)}{\cos(\theta)}$$

$$\psi=-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+c\right)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$$

$$b=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+c\right)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$$

Important : $c$ is a constant parameter with respect to $\phi$. But it can be a function of $\theta$.

$$b(\theta,\phi)=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$$

This solves Eq.$(3)$. The end of the task is for you. This will not be an easy task: Putting the above function $b(\theta,\phi)$ into Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ and checking if a function $g(\theta)$ exists  or not.

Comment: Thank-you for your helpful answer. I have followed through your working. I have suggested a small edit to fix four minus signs in the last four lines of your solution. Otherwise it seems perfect. I will proceed to attempt to finish the problem in the way you suggest. Thanks again.

Comment: You are right, there was a sign mistake. I accepted your suggested edit.

Comment: In notifications I read this : 
Leucippus reviewed this 7 hours ago: Reject
This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.
Harish Chandra Rajpoot reviewed this 7 hours ago: Reject
This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Comment: As far as I can understand from the rules of the forum : One is allowed to correct my own answer when they are mistakes in it. But one is not allowed to add something to my answer. You are allowed do edit your question and add  what you want into it.

Comment: I don't think that it is a good idea. I didn't reject your suggested addition. But this is not my own addition, so editing it in my answer is not the right place. Better edit it as an addition into your own question.

Comment: Meanwhile I checked the solution $b(\theta,\phi)$  with regard to Eq.$(1)$ . This appears not consistent. Thus the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not compatible one each other. Are you sure that there is no typo in  $(1)$ , $(2)$ or no mistake in the calculus leading to those equations ? I don't thing that it's a matter of boundary conditions for equations $(1)$ , $(2)$ .

Comment: I am puzzled by the proposition that Eqs. (1) and (2) are inconsistent. We will agree, I assume, that (1) and (2) as a system are equivalent to (2) and (3). And you have shown that your solution for $b(\theta,\phi)$ is consistent with (3), while I have shown that it is consistent with (2). Thus, we have a paradox to resolve.

Comment: I agree that explicit differentiation of $b(\theta,\phi)$ appears to yield the result $\frac{\partial b}{\partial \phi}=0$, which is inconsistent with (1). Thus I confirm the paradoxical situation. However the OP did say that there is perhaps no solution (option 1, and a bad outcome for my project). But how to resolve our paradox - one approach yields a solution, another none?

Comment: If $f(\phi)=0$, Eq. (1) is consistent. Do you concur?

Comment: I checked that $b(\theta,\phi)=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$ is solution of Eq.$(3)$ any function $g(\theta)$. But it is inconsistent with Eq.$(1)$ and inconsistent with Eq.$(2)$, even if $g(\theta)=0$. May be I am missing something but I see no paradox. Simply I think that the system of Eqs.$(1)$ and $(2)$ has no solution. Or there is a typo in it. Or I made a mistake in my checking calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Are you willing to share your proof that your $b(\theta,\phi)$ is inconsistent with Eq. (2)? I have demonstrated publicly above in the continuation to my original question that it is consistent with Eq. (2). I would like to understand this apparent disagreement. I checked, and there is no typo in Eqs. (1) and (2).

Comment: Of course I would like to share what Idid. But this is a much too long calculus. The principle of checking is very simple, but doing it is arduous. Starting from $b(\theta,\phi)=\phi-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan\big(\cos(\theta)\:\phi+g(\theta)\big)}{\cos(\theta)} \right)$. I compute $\frac{\partial b}{\partial \theta}$. I put them into $\frac{\partial b}{d\theta}  +\cos{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\sin{\left[\phi-b(\theta,\phi)\right]}\tan{\theta} $. For non-constant $\phi$ and non-constant $\theta\quad$ I observe that the result is not equal to $0$ as expected.

Comment: As I already mentioned this is a big calculus. Possibly there is a mistake. But I dit it completely two times  and obtained exactly the same result. Of course this is not a proof, but this convinced me.

Comment: Thank-you for your thoughts. I will explore some more tomorrow and let you know what I discover.